# Can ping and Google stuff, but not all websites are reachable

Tags: wireless, 19.04

I had a problem turning on a PC that remained off for a few weeks. Apparently the motherboard battery was not properly inserted so I simply took it off and on again. Now it works normally. Unfortunately, now I'm not able to connect to the Internet. I'm using a USB extender (Wi-Fi) to connect to the router and I notice that the Wi-Fi icon has a little question mark inside. I was not able to ping `google.com` and I changed the DNS from automatic to 8.8.8.8. Now I can ping, I can Google stuff and open **some** links (for instance, Twitter does not work while other random websites do!). I cannot even do a `git pull`.

What might be the cause?

Comment: Check your routes. `ip route show` and `ip -6 route show`. You should have a default route in each listing. I had similar behavior when my IPv4 route was not well set so that I was reaching only those sites for which my DNS was returning IPv6 addresses. Since I had no IPv4 route, I could not reach an IPv4 address.

Comment: I forgot to mention I had disabled IPv6. I turned it on again and did as you said. I have a default route for both.